# Marshalas UnManagedType for an array of Interface

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, com, interface

I have to put a MarshalType attribute for a member of a class that I need to invoke from C++ through COM.
The member of the class is an array of Interface IEmailAddress[].

Can someone please tell me what should be the value of the attribute in case of array of Interface.

```
[ProgId("EmailEntity")]
[Guid("44BEFE07-FDB7-413B-B14B-45A0F4EB6FA7")]    
public class EmailEntity : IEmailEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// BccRecipients
    /// </summary> 
    **public IEmailAddress[] BccRecipients;**

    /// <summary>
    /// Body
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Body;
```

}

Thanks,

Gagan

Comment: COM does not support fields, only properties and methods.  The answer to your previous question already showed you how to do this correctly.  It also told you to remove all [MarshalAs] attributes.  Please do not ignore good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a property:

```
public IEmailAddress[] BccRecipients {get;set;}
```